# Find a basis on the $n$-sphere's tangent space $\mathcal{T}_s\mathbb{S}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces, stereographic-projections

Let $\mathbb{S}^n$ be the $n$-sphere and $\mathcal{T}_s\mathbb{S}^n$ the tangent space at $\mathbf{s}\in\mathbb{S}^n$.

I am looking for a basis for the tangent $\mathcal{T}_s\mathbb{S}^n$, but I got confused.

Copying from Wikipedia, I understand that for a chart $\phi\colon\mathcal{U}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{S}^n$, one can define an ordered basis as follows:

[image]

My questions are: a) can $\phi$ be the ***stereographic projection*** from $\mathbb{S}^n-\{N\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (where $N$ denotes the north pole of $\mathbb{S}^n$), and b) what can $f$ be in that case?

Thank you!

Comment: You have two viewpoints here. The *extrinsic* one, in which your tangent space is an affine submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, and the *intrinsic* one, in which your tangent space is given in terms of differential operators (like in Wikipedia). If you want to follow the latter route, then you can use any chart. The stereographic projection is OK.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thanks for your comment. In the former case (intrinsically), I suppose you mean that I can use the standard basis and express everything wrt that (please correct me if I'm wrong). In the latter case, which is what I want, what would be a choice for the $f$ function? Could it be identical? Thanks for your time in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier by example. Let us think of $\mathbb S^2$, which is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. Denote the points of $\mathbb R^3$ as $(X,Y,Z)$.

In the extrinsic viewpoint, the tangent space at $(0,0,1)\in \mathbb S^2$ is the set $\{(X, Y, 1)\ :\ X,Y\in\mathbb R\}$.

In the intrinsic viewpoint, you need a chart. You seem to like the stereographic projection. The equations of such projection from the South Pole $(0,0,-1)$ are
$$\tag{1}
x=\frac{X}{1+Z},\quad y=\frac{Y}{1+Z},$$
with inverse
$$\tag{2}
X=\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2},\quad Y=\frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2},\quad Z=\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}.$$
The point $(X, Y, Z)=(0,0,1)$ corresponds to $x=0, y=0$. A basis of the tangent space at this point (and any other, except for the South Pole where the chart is undefined) is $\partial_x, \partial_y$.

For a $f\in C^\infty (\mathbb S^2)$ you can compute $\partial_x f|_{x=0, y=0}$ as follows. By definition, $f=f(X, Y, Z)$. So you plug in (2), yielding
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ F\left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}, \frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2}, \frac{1-x^2-y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}\right)\right]$$
and now you can compute and finally let $x=0, y=0$ in the result.

I hope this practical example clarified what is going on here.

---

Final notes.

1. This answer is the continuation of [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577251/fin-a-vector-basis-on-the-n-spheres-tangent-space-mathcalt-s-mathbbsn?noredirect=1#comment9634107_4577251)).
2. The original question asked about the stereographic projection from the North Pole, whereas here it is from the South Pole. There is no essential difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Even though it's clear, let me ask you a side question wrt the chart of choice. I mentioned the stereographic projection because I've used it before, but I have no apparent reasons to choose it over other charts. In fact this question came out of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576634/mahalanobis-like-distance-on-hypersphere.

Regardless of the other question (not trying to spam), would you mind pointing me to some other chart that would make sense? Thanks a lot!

Comment: We have a very nice chart right under our eyes here. Consider the upper half sphere $Z>0$. There, you can solve $$Z=\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2}$$ and so here's a chart: $$X=x, Y=y, Z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}, $$ which you can use on the upper half sphere.

Comment: I see, thanks very much for your time!